# Not seeing any shadows with a collada model on a MeshPhongMaterial ground and a spotlight

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've been trying to figure this out for ages but it's not working. I'm trying to add shadows to my .dea model, on a MeshPhongMaterial, but nothing is showing up.

The camera is correctly positioned, the ground is out of MeshPhongMaterial, the model casts Shadows and the ground can receive them.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

The relevant code bits:

```
function load() {
loader.load( 'models/charMesh_02_1.5.dae', function ( collada ) {
    model = collada.scene;
    model.scale.x = model.scale.y = model.scale.z = modelScale;
    model.castShadow = true;
    model.receiveShadow = true;
    modelmesh = model.children[0].children[0];
    modelmesh.castShadow = true;
    modelmesh.receiveShadow = true;
    model.updateMatrix();

    // When model is loaded, init and animate everything
    init();
    animate();
  });
}

//
// Set everything up
//
function init() {
container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );

// Camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );
camera.position.set( 2, 2, 400 );
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper() );

// Fog
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 1, 5000 );
scene.fog.color.setHSL( 0.6, 0, 1 );

// Light
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
light.shadowCameraNear = 2000;
light.shadowCameraFar = 3000;
light.shadowCameraLeft = -200;
light.shadowCameraRight = 200;
light.shadowCameraTop = 200;
light.shadowCameraBottom = -200;
light.position.set(-60, 1500, 1000);
scene.add(light);

// Ground
var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10000, 10000 );
var groundMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x959595 } );
groundMat.color.setHSL( 0.095, 1, 0.75 );
groundMat.shininess = 0;
groundGeo.receiveShadow = true;
groundMat.receiveShadow = true;
var ground = new THREE.Mesh( groundGeo, groundMat );
ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
ground.position.y = 0;
ground.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( ground );

// Skydome
var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;
var uniforms = {
    topColor: {type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x0077ff )},
    bottomColor: {type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff )},
    offset: {type: "f", value: 33},
    exponent: {type: "f", value: 0.6}
}
uniforms.topColor.value.copy(skydomeColor);
scene.fog.color.copy( uniforms.bottomColor.value );
var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 4000, 32, 15 );
var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader, uniforms: uniforms, side: THREE.BackSide});
var sky = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, skyMat);
scene.add(sky);

// Add the model
scene.add(model);

// Renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.shadowMapBias = 0.0039;
renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 0.5;
renderer.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
renderer.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
renderer.gammaInput = true;
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to traverse the model to set cast/receive shadow on each element.
When I load an object I do that :

```
function LoadDae(DaeFilename, name, scene) {
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

loader.load(DaeFilename, function (collada) {
 dae = collada.scene;
 dae.traverse(function (child) {
    child.castShadow = true;
    child.receiveShadow = true;
 });

 scene.add(dae);
});
}
```

Comment: So that almost worked, but now I get an

     `Unsupported light type for shadow`

error. Any ideas what could cause that? Definitely using DirectionalLight, which supports shadows...

Comment: No idea for me. Maybe search the error message in three.js in the source code.

Comment: Already done, but they basically just check if the light is an `instanceof THREE.DirectionalLight` or `THREE.SpotLight`, and if not, display this error message. My light is definitely a DirectionalLight though... (See [line 88 here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/9474428/))

Comment: Did you test instanceof in your code to verify the light ?

Comment: Good idea, using this code I get `yeah` in the console, so that seems alright.  `if(light instanceof THREE.DirectionalLight) {
  console.log("yeah");
 } else {
  console.log("wtf");
 }`

Comment: Did you set castShadow : directionalLight.castShadow = true; ?

Comment: Yeah, in my code you see `var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.castShadow = true;`, I think that's what you mean.